# C++: what does "T const *[]" mean?

Tags: c++

- what does "T const *[]" as parameter
  type mean?
- What's the difference
  compared to "T *[]"?
- And as last
  question: why can't I pass a "T *[]"
  to a function that requires a "T
  const * []" as parameter?

Thank you for your help.

Tobias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a type in general, it's an array of pointers to a constant T.
Try putting a name in it:

```
T const *x[];
```

and apply the usual rules: [] binds tighter than *, so it's an
array.  Then the * means that its an array of pointers, and
finally, they all point to a constant T.  (As usual, `const`
modifies whatever is to the left of it.)

As a parameter, of course, an array type is converted to
a pointer type, so we end up with a pointer to a pointer to
a constant T.  This could also be written:

```
T const **
```

If you drop the const, you end up with:

```
T **
```

which is not the same thing as `T const**`.

And the reason you can't pass a `T**` or a `T*[]` to the first
form is to prevent things like:

```
void f(int const* p1[]; int const* p2)
{
    p1[0] = *p2;
}
int const x = 10;
int* px[1];
f(px, &x);
*px[0] = 20;       //  Where does this write?
```

The fact that the declarations are written using [] is, in this
case, misleading, since the rules for pointers to pointers still
apply.

Answer (score 3):

It's an array of pointers to constant objects of type T (i.e. the pointer can change, but you cannot call a non-const function, or modify a non-mutable data member on these objects). T *[] is an array of pointers to non-const ojects. You can't pass T *[] to a function requiring a T const *[] as it would invalidate the const correctness of the pointers.

See [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.16) for more information.

Comment: did you read the stuff in your link? :) the pointer is not constant, the T is constant, right? you have to read it from right to left.

Comment: It might be worth adding that in code type T usually refers to a template parameter.  That is, the type is specified when the class is called: a_class<double> or a_class<int> or a_class<some_other_class> would be three different class types generated from template<class T> class a_class {};

Comment: @BTyler: I'd say `T const *[]` is an array of pointers to constant objects of type T. For an array of constant pointers to objects of type `T`, write `T * const []` instead. In the former case, the pointer can change, but the object it points to cannot; in the latter case, the pointer cannot change, but the object it points to can.

Comment: yes rturrado is right, why those upvotes to an incorrect answer?? :)

Comment: @rhurrato " In the former case, the pointer can change, but the object it points to cannot" - the link demonstrates the second half of this is incorrect.  The object can change - it just can't change through the pointer T const *.

Comment: I still can't see in your answer why it would violate const correctnes. If I have a non-const whatever, I should always be able to implicitly convert it to const whatever - since I'm already allowed to call everything. The other way round would violate const correctness.

Comment: @Tobias, I think the answer to your third point is in the next answer on the link 18.17.  I believe the array T *[] gets implictly converted to T * *.  I think the upshot is that you need to use to const specifier twice

Comment: I think the comments to this answer are now more useful than the answer itself.  I think the answer should be made into a community wiki.  I don't have rep to do this.

Comment: In my humble opinion, some of the comments are a bit confusing (or confused?) and misleading. Though I agree that the wording in B Tyler's answer ("constant pointer") is maybe a bit unlucky as it is not 100% unambiguous, he is nevertheless explaining the right thing, an array of pointers which themselves are mutable but cannot change the objects they point to. If one reads the parenthesis, it is exactly identical to what rturrado says later. Though he got the invalidation of const correctness the wrong way around (probably meant the right thing, but got it the wrong way)...

Comment: ... the right way would be "passing a const type to a non-const function will break const correctness". If you pass a non-const type to a function that promises to treat it as const, no evil things happen. The compiler couldn't care less (except maybe being able to do one or the other optimization). Only if you have a type that is const and pass it to a function with a non-const signature, the compiler can't be sure that you don't break the "will not modify" promise that you gave earlier.

Comment: Wow, serious vitriol! lol. Right answer, right link, slight issue on semantics. @Damon --> Cheers. I've updated that now.